# Startup freeze, Games crash, Youtube crashes, no sound

Tags: drivers, uefi, startup, asus, steam

I have installed Ubuntu for the first time on my Asus k55n, and it fails sometimes to boot up to the normal login screen, it usually just is purple and has dots, Steam games crash as soon as I boot them, the sound icon on the top right has the speaker with --- coming out of it, and no options when I click on it... I'm really confused, My BIOS is UEFI, Things like Blender, or open TTD will refuse to open as well, could it just be that Ubuntu doesnt recognize my graphics card(s)?

### Youtube

Youtube loads, and as soon as it plays, firefox completely crashes, Firefox also crashes whenever I try and right click anything. I currently have flash, and the extras.

Comment: I am using 12.04

Comment: You can edit information into your Question at any time if you want to add information. Welcome to askubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

## Video and Sound

Boot into Ubuntu and start the program "Software and Updates" (or similar, I'm not using it in english). This program has a few Tabs, the last Tab should be named "Additional Drivers". You can choose a fitting proprietary driver there and apply it. You'll be asked for a password. It will install it automatically, which will take a while. You'll need this for many steam games, especially 3D games.

If you are lucky there is also a driver for your sound card, which may solve your Audio problems. According to the Asus homepage, they seem to have an unusual ("Sonic Master Lite, Altec Lansing® Speakers") Soundsystem.

Fixing the video problem could maybe also fix your booting problem, but this is just a guess. I'm not experienced with UEFI but you could take a look into it and show whether it offers something useful. Like disabling some secure boot features or something.

## Youtube

Youtube should work if you use Firefox and install this plugin: 
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/

It works at least for me. I also recommend in any case to install this if you did not already:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/

This will give you support for many non-free codecs and more. With this, everything should work. If not, it's probably related to your video card / gaming problem I guess.

Comment: There is no sound drivers in the manager, I turned on my video drivers, but still cant seem to play anything, the boot problem seems to be fixed... I have tried reinstalling with the boot cd, but when i press install its a black screen. I also tried running the update manager, I updated everything, and still same issues

Comment: Could it be because im running a 32 bit Ubuntu on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: I've never tried 32bit Ubuntu, so I don't know. But I would not wonder if games are optimized for and tested on 64 systems. I can say that Steam ans it's games work good on a 64bit Ubuntu for me. I'd say it's worth a try. Does Youtube work now?

Comment: No, youtube still does not work

Comment: I added a youtube section to my answer. I hope it helps. If not can you maybe describe (in your Question above) in which way youtube does not work? By the way, Blender normally should not need a proprietary driver, now that I think about it. Maybe a fresh 64bit install is really a good idea.

Comment: Ill try to do a fresh install and ill write if it fixed or not tomorrow.